# How can i upload image with CkFinder in Spring security?

Tags: java, spring-security

I have integrated CkFinder into CkEditor in a Spring MVC web app, with Spring Security.
However, in CkFinder, if you want to upload images, you must turn off csrf in the spring security configuration

if csrf is enable get error:

POST http://localhost:8080/controller/ckfinder/core/connector/java/connector.java?command=FileUpload&type=Images&currentFolder=%2F&langCode=vi&hash=cb5221931a8be9586fc545ef7c7283c8&response_type=txt 405 (Method Not Allowed)

So is there any way to upload images in CkFinder without having to disable the csrf? Who knows this only helps me.

This is Spring security configuration

```
<http auto-config="true">       
    <csrf disabled="true"/> 
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**"
        access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**"
        access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />
    <form-login login-page="/loginform"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginform?error=true" />
    <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/" />
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
</http>
```

Comment: Try adding this line at the end of your POST url  "?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}"

Comment: it should be like "http://localhost:8080/controller/ckfinder/core/connector/java/connector.java?command=FileUpload&type=Images&currentFolder=%2F&langCode=vi&hash=cb5221931a8be9586fc545ef7c7283c8&response_type=txt?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}"

Comment: Also make sure the enctype attribute is added to your form/uploader. refer to this https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp